# How to make the difference between a normal search and a global search

Tags: android, search

I would like to know if there is a way to make a difference between a normal search and a global search in Android. Isn't there any property of the intent I could use to make a difference between the two kind of searches ?

Thanks in advance,
 Stéphane

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So Will kru is right. It is possible to add some data to my search intent inside myactivity to distinguish it from a global search.

Here are some references : 
Passing some data to search, from android dev 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html#SearchContextData

And here is some example code.

```
@Override
public boolean onSearchRequested() {
     Bundle appData = new Bundle();
     appData.putBoolean(SearchableActivity.JARGON, true);
     startSearch(null, false, appData, false);
     return true;
 }
```

Thanks @Will Kru,
 Stéphane

Answer (score 0):

When implementing a searchbox within your app, you are responsible for providing search results. By global search I guess you mean the quick search box within the Android OS. You can register your app to it, so it's search results will show up when users search using this box.

Refer to the [android developer blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/09/introducing-quick-search-box-for.html) for more info on how to implement this.

Comment: Hello Will, thanks for taking time to answer. 

But I know how to implement this. The trouble I have is that I want to be able to have different behavior in my app for search when it is called by the quick search box than when it is called by the search key.

Comment: Ah I see, you want to be able to determine from which box the search came. How about adding an extra field to the intent that is sent from your app's searchbox? Within your search result resolver you could check for this extra data and if it exists, the search was done through your app's search box?